# `ctrl-o` but within the current file

Tags: jumplist

I was working on `data.md` a day ago and worked on numerous other files from then till now. I'd like to go back to my last position in `data.md` without touching other files.

Using `ctrl-o` would make me go through other files I've worked on in between. I'd like a `ctrl-o`/`ctrl-i` equivalent for jumping around only in the current file.

What's a good way to jump through the jump list but only within the current file?

Answer (score 2):

`'"` Will jump to the last position the cursor was when you last left the buffer.
`:he '"` for more info.

You can set this up automatically, with the snippet found at `:he last-position-jump`

Just to clarify, CTRL-O moves you through the jumplist, whereas `'"` is moving you to an automatically created mark.

Another nice tip is `gi` which will put you into insert mode at the position you last inserted text

Comment: g; and g, are a recent addition to my repertoire for moving through the change list

Comment: g; and g, are great.